# Android: how to tell if I have privileges to open a directory?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my file browser, I can read the list of directories and files say in "/" but in that list, some directories require higher privileges to be opened and browsed (root, data etc). Is there a way to detect these before I display them? If the user can't open the directory, I don't want to display it.

I think I'm looking for an AccessControlException but I'm not sure how and when I should be expecting it.

Grateful for any advice.

Baz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below snippet might help

```
File file = new File(path);
boolean canRead = file.canRead();
```

Comment: Many, many thanks. Such a short piece of code; such a long time wondering how to fix it; 3 minutes between asking the question and getting a fix. I love this site (and the generous contributors to it). Baz.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods :  `MYFile.canExecute`; `MYFile.canRead`; `MYFile.canWrite` return true if you can execute, read or write the file (or directory)

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canExecute()